# different definitions of Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, hopf-algebras

(i). In the book [Algebraic Topology, A. Hatcher, p. 283](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch3.4.pdf)， the notion *Hopf algebra* is defined as follows:
[image]

(ii). However, in the book [Bialgebras and Hopf algebras, J.P. May](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/TQFT/HopfAll.pdf), the notion *Hopf algebra* is defined as follows:[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question:** why the definition in (ii) is much more complicated than the definition in (i)? Are the two definitions of Hopf algebra in (i) and (ii) equivalent or different? I do not understand the definition in (ii).

**Another question:** for an $H$-space (we can strengthen to topological monoid up to homotopy) $X$ and coefficient ring $R$, will the homology
$$
H_*(X;R)
$$
be a Hopf algebra according to the definition in (ii)?

Comment: I think both of them are equivalent. The second gives the definitions of associative algebra with unit and coassociative coalgebra with counit in detail as you see. I don't think it is too complicate. I hope it help :)

Comment: The most obvious difference in the definitions is that May wants an antipode, but Hatcher doesn't. I've seen several people who take a Hopf algebra without antipode, whilst others refer to this structure as a bialgebra and require that a Hopf algebra has an antipode.

Comment: Also Hatcher assumes his algebra is graded, which is not standard.

Comment: Dear @ChrisGodsil, both do, but yes, it seems non-standard to meet too. Anyway, I tried to verify that the Hopf algebras of Hatcher's are Hopf algebras in the other sense, after choosing appropriate (co-)augmentation and antipode, but it seems there is no reason for the comultiplication to be coassociative!?

Comment: One can show that Hatcher's Hopf algebras have an antipode. This follows from gradedness. Classically, the Holf algebras under consideration were graded, so the antipode was not mentioned. This should be discussed in any textbook on the subject, like the one by Susan Montgomery.

Comment: Hatcher's Hopf algebras are graded simply because his Hopf algebras come from the homology of H-spaces.

Comment: Dear @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, why is the comultiplication in Hatcher's definition coassociative? From a quick search on how to get an antipode on a graded bialgebra, it seems coassociativity is used in the construction.

Comment: It isn't. It is trivial to construct examples. I meant, the ones he is interested in, those coming from H-spaces.

Answer (score 3):

[Note: After the comments to this answer and the question, there have been major changes. Thanks to Najib Idrissi, the situation is much clearer now.]

There are only slight differences in the definitions and strictly speaking, Hatcher's is more general. In addition to (equivalents of) Hatcher's axioms, May wants a Hopf algebra to be flat (a minor technical additional assumption) and the comultiplication to be coassociative. Furthermore, it remains unclear (to me) whether coassociativity is automatic in Hatcher's definition.

To make it clear, a Hopf algebra in the sense of Hatcher's is one in May's definition, if in addition

1. $A$ is flat as $R$-module and
2. $\Delta$ is coassociative, i.e., makes the left hand side diagram in May's definition 2.2 commute.

(Perhaps coassociativity is automatic, but I don't see why.)
For how to define the antipode, see [this blog post](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/why-graded-bi-algebras-have-antipodes/).
The unit(=coaugmentation) should be taken to be the algebra structure map $R\to A$ and the augmentation $A\to R$ should be taken the projection $A\to A_0\cong R$.

The other way around, given a Hopf algebra $(A,\varphi,\psi,\eta,\varepsilon,\chi)$ as May wants it, then $\psi(\alpha) = 1\otimes\alpha+\alpha\otimes 1+\sum_i\alpha'_i\otimes\alpha''_i$ follows from the commutativity of the right hand side diagram in 2.2 and the fact that $A_0 = R$ via the unit and counit. The commutativity of the diagram in 3.2 as well as the second one in definition 2.2 show that $\psi$ is a homomorphism of algebras.

An example of a Hopf algebra as in Hatcher's which isn't a Hopf algebra as in May's definition would need to be non-coassociative (besides maybe non-flatness, which wouldn't be satisfactory). As I said before, I don't know if this is automatic or not.

Comment: The existence of the antipode is automatic in Hatcher's version, since they are connected Hopf algebras (graded in nonnegative degrees, and the degree zero part is the base ring) -- at the very least in the associative+coassociative case, I don't know if it still holds otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, @NajibIdrissi. I wonder, is there a reason why in a graded Hopf algebra, the comultiplication should look like primitive+(positive degree stuff)? I see why Hatcher assumes it, but is there a formal reason we should care for these without saying "we only care for H-spaces here"?

Comment: It's a consequence of being connected and of the counit relations, no?

Comment: Aah, of course! I guess I'm just not used to graded Hopf algebras... I'll edit the post later. Perhaps, when it turns out coassociativity is for free too, there will not be much left of the original answer.

Comment: Coassociativity is not an automatic consequence of Hatcher's axioms. For example, one can take the algebra of symmetric functions, and endow it with a comultiplication given by $\Delta \left(h_n\right) = h_n \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes h_n $ $+ \left(\text{some arbitrary combination of the } h_m \otimes h_{n-m} \text{ with } 1 \leq m \leq n-1\right)$ (extended to the whole algebra by the universal property, since we want $\Delta$ to be an algebra homomorphism). Most of the time this will not be coassociative. Probably we can construct a left antipode and a right antipode, but no two-sided one.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been successfully answered if you combine the other answers and the comment discussion that they contain. I will summarize:

There are various differences between the definitions. First is a technical one: May requires flatness of certain modules. Although this condition is technically important for some statements, it is inconsequential when it comes to the moral differences between the definitions. Anyway, you can (and should) ask about the difference over a field, where every module is flat.

Second, Hatcher asks that a Hopf algebra be connected. This condition allows him to drop any explicit reference to an antipode:

**Proposition:** Suppose that $H = \bigoplus_n H_n$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded bialgebra over $R$, associative unital and coassociative counital, which is *connected* in the sense that $H_{<0} = 0$ and $H_0 = R$. Then $H$ has an *antipode*.

For later linguistic ease, I'll call the grading on $H$ the *cohomological grading*. But this is just a name.

Recall that the multiplication $m$ and comultiplication $\Delta$ together supply a *convolution product* to $\operatorname{End}(H)$, given by $f \star g = m \circ (f \otimes g) \circ \Delta$, which is unital and associative if $H$ is both unital associative and counital coassociative. An *antipode* is a (two-sided) $\star$-inverse to the identity map. (In particular, the antipode is unique if it exists, so that it is a *property*, not structure, for a bialgebra to admit an antipode.)

[Ben](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12885/ben) already supplied a link to a proof. But I want to present a proof strategy that is very general, and applies to lots of similar cases, because I think it is good to see it:

**Proof:** Let $I = \bigoplus_{n>0} H_n$. Since $H_{<0} = 0$, $I$ is both an ideal and a coideal, and so $H / I^m$ is Hopf. Moreover, since $I^m$ is supported in cohomoligcal degree $\geq m$, $H$ is isomorphic, as a cohomoligcally-graded bialgebra, to its $I$-adic completion:
$$ H \cong \varprojlim_{m \to \infty} H / I^m.$$
Let $\operatorname{gr}(H)$ denote the associated graded of the filtration $H \supset I \supset I^2 \supset \dots$. In other words,
$$ \operatorname{gr}(H) = \bigoplus_{m \geq 0} I^m / I^{m+1}.$$
This new grading is in addition to the cohomological grading. But I remark in passing that $I^m/I^{m+1}$ is supported in cohomological degree $\geq m$, and so $\operatorname{gr}(H)$ is also equal, as a cohomologically-graded object, to the infinite product $\prod_{m\geq 0} I^m/I^{m+1}$.

In any case, $\operatorname{gr}(H)$ is a bialgebra, generated as a ring by $I/I^2$. Just from considering degrees (with respect to the new grading), you see that for any generator $x \in I/I^2$, $\Delta x$ must be a linear combination of $x \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes x$; from counitality, we must have $\Delta x = x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x$, or in other words $x$ is *primitive*. But then setting $S(x) = -x$ on the generators supplies an antipode.

Now the trick is to continuously interpolate between $H$ and $\operatorname{gr}(H)$. This trick goes under the name *Rees*. What I'll do is to introduce a new formal variable $\epsilon$. Now look at the sum
$$ X = H[\epsilon] \oplus I[\epsilon] \oplus I^2[\epsilon] \oplus \dots = \bigoplus_{m \geq 0} I^m[\epsilon]_m = \bigoplus_{m\geq 0} X_m,$$
where the subscript "$m$" just keeps track of which summand we are in. I remark in passing that, in the cohomologically-graded world, I can ignore whether this is an infinite sum or an infinite product, since the $m$th summand is supported in cohomological degrees $\geq m$. Now to this total sum $X$, I'll impose the following relation: for any $x \in X_m$, let me write $x_{m-1}$ for "the same" element thought of in $X_{m-1}$ (via the canonical map $X_m \hookrightarrow X_{m-1}$); now force $x_{m-1} \equiv \epsilon x$ for all $x \in X_m$.

I will call this quotient $\operatorname{Rees}(H)$. It is by construction an object over the polynomial ring $R[\epsilon]$. Note that:
$$ \operatorname{Rees}(H) / (\epsilon = 0) = \operatorname{gr}(H), \quad \operatorname{Rees}(H) / (\epsilon \neq 0) = H,$$
where by "$\epsilon \neq 0$" I mean for any invertible value of $\epsilon$.

Moreover, $\operatorname{Rees}(H)$ turns out to be a (cohomologically-graded) bialgebra over $R[\epsilon]$. The last step is then a rather standard application of the following idea (but translated into algebraic geometry): the existence of $S$ is the statement that something, somewhere, is invertible; but invertibility is an open condition; so, since $S$ exists when $\epsilon = 0$, it exists for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small; but there are small invertible numbers.

Ok, that wasn't a convincing paragraph except maybe when $R = \mathbb{R}$, and even then it's sketchy. But the real argument is essentially the same: you show from very abstract principles that the region where $S$ exists is an intersection of countably many Zariski-open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec}(R[\epsilon])$, and that this intersection contains $0$, but then this intersection contains an invertible value of $\epsilon$.

Let me make this argument completely explicit in the case when $R$ is a field. In this case, you can (arbitrarily) choose a splitting of the inclusion $I^{m+1} \subset I^m$, i.e. you can set $I^m \cong J_m \oplus I^{m+1}$. Having made these arbitrary choices, you find vector space isomorphisms $H \cong \bigoplus J_m \cong \operatorname{gr}(H)$.

These vector space isomorphisms also provide a vector space decomposition of the Rees algebra: as a vector space, $\operatorname{Rees}(H) \cong H[\epsilon ]\cong \operatorname{gr}(H)[\epsilon ]$.  Moreover, the comultiplication and multiplication on $\operatorname{Rees}(H)$ differ from those on $\operatorname{gr}(H)[\epsilon ]$ by terms of order $\epsilon$. So you take the antipode $S_{\epsilon=0}$ on $\operatorname{gr}(H)$, and try to use it as an antipode for $\operatorname{Rees}(H)$, and calculate how far off you are, and you find: $S_{\epsilon=0} \star \operatorname{id} = 1_\star + \text{error}$, where $1_\star$ is the unit for the convolution product, and $\text{error}$ is of order $\epsilon$. But now you are in business, because $\star$ is bilinear, and so you how to invert things of the form $1 + O(\epsilon)$:
$$ (1_\star + \text{error})^{-1} = 1 - \text{error} + \text{error}^2 - \text{error}^3 + \dots.$$
And the true antipode would be
$$S_\epsilon = (1 + \text{error})^{-1} \star S_{\epsilon=0}.$$

Well, this would work as soon as this power series converges. This is where I come back to my constant refrain that I can ignore the difference between sums and products. See, in addition to being order $\epsilon$, the error term also strictly-raises the (noncohomological) degree. So the sum converges if you think of it as a map from the infinite sum to the infinite product. $\Box$

There is one more difference between the two proposed definitions of "Hopf algebra": May (and Wikipedia) requires a Hopf algebra to be coassociative, and Hatcher does not.

This is a nontrivial difference, as pointed out by [darij grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg).

**Counterexample:** Consider a polynomial ring $H = R[h_1, h_2, h_3]$, in which the generator $h_i$ is in degree $i$ (and I'm not doing any Koszul signs, I just mean a totally-bosonic ordinary polynomial ring; so if you want, place $h_i$ instead in degree $2i$). Counitality and degree considerations force:
$$ \Delta h_1 = h_1 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes h_1,$$
$$ \Delta h_2 = h_2 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes h_2 + \alpha h_1 \otimes h_1,$$
$$ \Delta h_3 = h_3 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes h_3 + \beta h_2 \otimes h_1 + \gamma h_1 \otimes h_2,$$
for some constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in R$.

Slightly remarkably, for any $\alpha$, the subalgebra $R[h_1,h_2]$ is coassociative. However:
$$ (\Delta \otimes \operatorname{id})\Delta h_3 - (\operatorname{id} \otimes \Delta)\Delta h_3 = \alpha(\beta -\gamma) h_1 \otimes h_1 \otimes h_1.$$
So this is coassociative iff $\alpha(\beta -\gamma) = 0$.